# Is there a way to import a function using Next.js dynamic import? react-component-export-image issues with Next.js ssr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was getting the 'window is not defined' error when importing `react-component-export-image` so I used a dynamic import to get around that. I don't get that error anymore but now I get '`exportComponentAsPNG(componentRef)` is not a function'. Is there a better way to deal with the 'window is not defined' error or a way to use the function I am importing dynamically? If not, is there a different npm library that works to generate an image from a react component?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
// import { exportComponentAsPNG } from 'react-component-export-image' *This gave window not defined error so I used dynamic import*
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import ProductCard from '../ProductCard/ProductCard.component'
import Button from '../Button/Button.component'

const { exportComponentAsPNG } = dynamic(
  () => import('react-component-export-image'),
  {
    ssr: false
  }
)

const Plaque = () => {
 const componentRef = useRef()

  // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
  const ComponentToPrint = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        <ProductCard />
      </div>
    )
  })

  return (
        <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
          <button onClick={() => exportComponentAsPNG(componentRef)}> // "Error: exportComponentAsPNG is not a function"
          Export As PNG
        </button>
  )
}

export default Plaque
```

Comment: What happens if you create a `handleClick()` function which calls `exportComponentAsPNG(componentRef)` and then just place `() => handleClick()` in your `onClick`

Comment: @MarkWilliams I gave that a shot but I still get `TypeError: exportComponentAsPNG is not a function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exportComponentAsPNG` function needs access to `window` which is undefined with server side rendering. I was able to fix the issue by dynamically importing the `Plaque` component that used `exportComponentAsPNG` to the page where it is called with sever side rendering set to 'false'.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Plaque = dynamic(() => import('../compnonents/Plaque'), {
  ssr: false
})

const Page = () => {
  return <Plaque />
}

export default Page
```

Now that the component is no longer using SSR I was able to import and use the function normally.

```
import { exportComponentAsPNG } from 'react-component-export-image'
```

Here you can find the documentation for the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-export-image

Answer (score 4):

`next/dynamic` is used to dynamically import React components, not regular JavaScript functions or libraries.

For that, you can use a regular dynamic import on `exportComponentAsPNG` inside the `onClick` callback.

```js
<button onClick={async () => {
    const { exportComponentAsPNG } = await import('react-component-export-image')
    exportComponentAsPNG(componentRef)
}}>
```

Comment: Thank you, I found another solution that worked and I just posted that one. I will give this a shot too and let you know if it works!

Comment: thank you, only this solution worked for me while using a [3rd-party library](https://github.com/thumbmarkjs/thumbmarkjs/discussions/5#discussioncomment-8425253) that didn't have a document check in place. none of the other dynamic solutions worked.